# node js, obtener en una variable el contenido de una consulta asincrónica

Tags: javascript, nodejs, async-await

Buenas estoy intentando hacer una consulta 'select' a la base de datos desde index.js para tomar los elementos de la tabla 'mercancia' y luego pasar ese contenido a una variable, pero al ejecutar me sale 'Promise {<pending}' y no se copia la información  en la variable que quiero, alguien que pueda ayudarme...

```
const getProducts= async() => {
  try{
  let res = await pool.query('select * from mercancia');
  let result =  res.rows;
  return  result ;
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
};

let products=getProducts();
console.log(products);
```

Comment: Igual debes de esperar cuando mandas a llamar a `getProducts()`, lo puedes hacer con un `.then()` o si está dentro de un contexto asíncrono con un `await`. Imagina que ahorita mandas a Juan a pedirle a María que te escriba una carta, Juan espera a María, pero tú ya te fuiste y Juan no ha regresado. Eso es lo que está pasando

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que, como usas asincronia, este al esperar una respuesta le tienes que indicar que le prometes que tendrá un resultado en el momento, en el futuro o nunca. Pueden tener diferentes sintaxis, desde iniciar tu mismo una promesa, hasta estar usando funciones que deben de ser promesas; tendrías que buscar la mejor, para mi, pienso que es esta

---

*Codigo sin probar*

```
let res = pool.query('select * from mercancia').promise();
//El await solamente es necesario cuando quieres esperar tu respuesta,
//puedes poner a trabajar en otras cosas mientras esto se ejecuta, 
//y luego, cuando ya necesites tu respuesta usas
await res;
```

Con esto echo, puedes hacer varias cosas con tu variable `res` las cuales, en sintaxis, son

```
res.then((output) => output.json())
    .then(data => result = data.rows);
```

también puedes capturar los errores

```
.catch(
    function(reason) {
      console.log('Manejar promesa rechazada ('+reason+') aquí.');
    });
```

Todos estos puedes utilizarlos como extensiones de tu variable res, siempre y cuando esperes a su respuesta y le hagas una promesa. Actualmente estoy trabajando con dynamodb, y me pasó exactamente lo mismo que te pasa, y agregando el `.promise()` fue que solucioné mi problema

Te sugiero [leer un poco de promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)